# Is a snowflake schema better than a star schema for data mining?

Tags: sql, schema, data-warehouse, star-schema, snowflake-schema

I know the basic difference between a star schema and a snowflake schema-a snowflake schema breaks down dimension tables into multiple tables in order to normalize them, a star schema has only one "level" of dimension tables. But the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) for Snowflake Schema says

"Some users may wish to submit queries to the database which, using conventional multidimensional reporting tools, cannot be expressed within a simple star schema. This is particularly common in data mining of customer databases, where a common requirement is to locate common factors between customers who bought products meeting complex criteria. Some snowflaking would typically be required to permit simple query tools to form such a query, especially if provision for these forms of query weren't anticipated when the data warehouse was first designed."

When would it be impossible to write a query in a star schema that could be written in a snowflake schema for the same underlying data? It seems like a star schema would always allow the same queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For data mining, you almost always have to prepare your data -- mostly as one "flat table".

It may be a query, prepared view or CSV export -- depends on the tool and your preference.

Now, to properly understand that article, one would probably have to smoke-drink the same thing as the author when he/she wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, preparing a flat table for data mining starting from a relational database is no simple task, and the snowflake or the star schema only work up to a point.

However, there is a software called [Dataconda](http://www.dataconda.net) that automatically creates a flat table from a DB.

Basically, you select a target table in a relational database, and dataconda "expands" it by adding thousands new attributes to it; these attributes are obtained by executing complex queries involving multiple tables.